# How can I return a user input as a variable, to be called by another script?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to return a user input value from a GUI I made with Tkinter, I want this to be stored as a variable, so I can use the import from function in another script to call back this value (for calculations).

I have tried assigning multiple functions to the button, and setting the variable from within a def.

The four scripts at the bottom are working perfectly with the GUI, however, I currently have them set to yardstick = input() - thus prompting the user to input the value into the console, I would like this to be done from within the GUI when selecting the model. (think yardstick = v) from the code below.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- main ---

scripts = ["CPS.py", "BPS.py", "WWI.py", "WWSST.py",]

OPTIONS = ["Combined Pumping Stations", "Booster Pumping Station", "Waste Water Ionisation", "Waste Water Sludge Storage Tanks (Concrete)"]

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Birch Forest')
root.minsize(500,200)

# --- Listbox ---

tk.Label(root, text='Element Name', bg='#00C78C').pack(fill='x')

l = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode='single')

l.pack(side="left", fill="both",expand=True)
l.insert('end', *OPTIONS)

# --- Textbox ---

def printtext():
    global e
    string = e.get() 
    v = (string)
    print(v)

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

b = tk.Button(root,text='Save',command=printtext)
b.pack(side='bottom')


# --- functions --- 
def on_button():

    # different examples with `curselection()`

    for idx in l.curselection():
        if OPTIONS[idx] == 'Combined Pumping Stations':
            print("Running Random Forest Simulation")
        elif OPTIONS[idx] == 'Booster Pumping Stations':
            print("Running Random Forest Simulation")
        elif OPTIONS[idx] == 'Waste Water Ionisation':
            print("Running Random Forest Simulation")
        elif OPTIONS[idx] == 'Waste Water Sludge Storage Tanks (Concrete)':
            print("Running Random Forest Simulation")

    for idx in l.curselection():
        if idx == 0:
            import CPS
        elif idx == 1:
            import BPS
        elif idx == 2:
            import WWI
        elif idx == 3:
            import WWSST
            
# --- Button ---

b = tk.Button(root, text='Run Simulation', bg='#76EEC6', command=on_button)
b.pack(fill = "x", side="right", expand = True)

root.mainloop()
```

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Put simply; I would like v on line 28 to return as a variable in the variable explorer so I can call on it in script CPS when determining the yardstick value.

Comment: Can you provide some code so we can see what you've tried so far?

Comment: Lightning fast Collin! I was having trouble formatting the code for Stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't understand your question or the code in it. When I run it, a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxx'` is raised depending on the `Listbox` item selected, so the other scripts don't work "perfectly with the GUI". The global variable `scripts` is not used anywhere. You don't mention these thing in the question, but go on about passing the user input (from the `Entry` widget in a variable named `yearstick` I think) to one of those external scripts. Please [edit] your question again and clarify what exactly it is you want to know.

Comment: Good morning @martineau, I have included 2 pictures which may help explain my problem.

I would like to know how to have a user input return as a variable, so I can call on that variable from another script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially what you want to do is share data between the main script and some others that it `import`s. A good way to do this is by storing that data in a module and import`ing it into all scripts the want access to these values.

First create an empty script file, for example `shared.py`.

Then add an `import shared` to the beginning of your main script (i.e. `Birchforest.py`).

After that, modify the 'Save' button callback `printtext()` so it stores the value in a named attribute of this module:

```
import shared
.
.
.
# --- Textbox ---

def printtext():
    global e
    shared.v = e.get()  # Store current Entry value in shared module.
```

Lastly, you must do add an `import shared` the beginning of the scripts that are going to be `import`ed by the main script (i.e. `CPS.py`, `BPS.py`, etc) so they can access to this shared data.

For example:

```
import shared

print('in CPS')
print('  shared.v:', shared.v)

... # rest of script
```

After doing this they will be able to access any values that the main script has put into the `shared` module's namespace.

This works because `import`ed modules are cached in `sys.modules`, and if another script `import`s a module that has already be `import`ed by some other script, the cached value is used instead of reloading and executing the named script again.

This effectively means that modules are implemented in a way that means they follow the [Singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)—because they're instances of `types.ModuleType` class.

If you wish you can define defaults for values of the attributes, in which case `shared.py` would no longer be empty. Keep in mind however, that changes made to those values at runtime via assignment statements in any other module will *not* be persistent since the changes are only being made to in the in-memory version of the module (cached in the `sys.modules` list), not to the corresponding script `.py` file itself.

A similar idea is described in the [How do I share global variables across modules?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules) section of the online documentation.